# Rally: v2.0 API Authorization within Node.js to handle POST requests

Tags: node.js, express, rally

I created a small server in Node.js to handle Rally POST requests. This has been working until I updated to the Rally v2.0 API. With the new authorization model, I'm not sure what I have to do to my server so that I no longer get 'Not authorized to perform action: Invalid Key'. I read the Rally authorization doc but I'm not sure how to apply it within the server. Here's what I have that doesn't work:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var sys = require('util');
var client = require('restler');
var userNamePassword = { 'username': 'myusername', 'password': 'mypassword' };
app.use(express.bodyParser());

app.all('/rally/projectpermission/create', function(req, res)
{
  client.get("https://rally.eng.xxxx.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/security/authorize", userNamePassword)
  .on('complete', function(data, response)
  {
    var result = JSON.parse(data);
    var operationResult = result['OperationResult'];
    securityToken = operationResult['SecurityToken'];

    var p = 'https://rally.eng.xxxx.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/projectpermission/create?key=_SECURITY_TOKEN_'.replace('_SECURITY_TOKEN_', securityToken);

    client.postJson(p, req.body, userNamePassword)
    .on('complete', function(data, response)
    {
      res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
      res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
      res.json(response.statusCode);
    })
    .on('success', function(data, response)
    {
      console.log('success: ' + data);
    })
    .on('fail', function(data, response)
    {
      console.log('fail: ' + data);
    })
    .on('error', function(err, response)
    {
      console.log('error: ' + err);
    });
  });
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you're including the credentials on the get request to /security/authorize it should work.  Are you getting a valid key back?

We have also recently released a Node.js toolkit for working with Rally's WSAPI.  It handles all of this authentication for you and also makes a lot of the other operations like querying easier.

Check it out: https://github.com/rallytools/rally-node

Comment: The key appears to be valid. It's a key similar to: 76d52bb4-678e-430e-a851-4ec063d800ae. So, are you saying that the my code should work? I'll also look at the toolkit you mentioned. I'm just learning in this area but is there an issue with session control?

Comment: The key looks to be valid and it seems you are including it correctly in your request.  There is also a bug in Rally where sometimes it incorrectly says your key is invalid- but if your code never works there is probably something else going on.

Comment: I just used the toolkit and that solved my problem. I'll